# Uncommonly used Java syntax (JavaParser)?

Tags: java, algorithm, syntax, syntax-error

I'm exploring a Java grammar parser and I came across this strange piece of code that I wouldn't normally use in ordinary code. Taken from 
https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/source/browse/branches/mavenized/JavaParser/src/main/java/japa/parser/ASTParser.java#1998

It has many functions that contains code such as

```
final public NameExpr Name() throws ParseException {
    NameExpr ret;
    jj_consume_token(IDENTIFIER);
    ret = new NameExpr(token.beginLine, token.beginColumn, token.endLine, token.endColumn, token.image);
    label_23: while (true) {
        if (jj_2_17(2)) {
            ;
        } else {
            break label_23;
        }
        jj_consume_token(DOT);
        jj_consume_token(IDENTIFIER);
        ret = new QualifiedNameExpr(ret.getBeginLine(), ret.getBeginColumn(), token.endLine, token.endColumn, ret, token.image);
    }
    {
        if (true) {
            return ret;
        }
    }
    throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");
}
```

At a glance it appears strange but no doubt it's valid as I can compile it. But can someone explain how it works? I have tried to input invalid Java syntax and it does it's job! I'm baffled. How does the few lines throw exception after the return?

Comment: Make sure to identify the *exact* code/syntax that is not understood: i.e. is it "labels"? An "empty statement"? A "useless throw"?

Comment: I can't really provide an answer since I have never came across something like this, but this seems to be outlined in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) Oracle Tutorial.

Comment: Yes, it's the block labels, extra pair of braces surrounding the return, useless if statement and unreachable throw that I'm referring to.

Comment: That is one weird piece of code.

Comment: It looks like a generated code. Maybe from ANTRL?

Comment: break to a label is goto's evil cousin

Comment: This is generated code, not ANTRL but JavaCC. It is a parser, as most parsers are it is generated from a grammar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed valid code, without seeing everything, I can see some odditities:

- 'Incorrect' variable and method naming, using PascalCase sometimes.
- Instance variable `token`
- Static variable `IDENTIFIER`

Then:

```
label_23: while (true) {
    if (jj_2_17(2)) {
        ;
    } else {
        break label_23;
    }
    jj_consume_token(DOT);
    jj_consume_token(IDENTIFIER);
    ret = new QualifiedNameExpr(ret.getBeginLine(), ret.getBeginColumn(), token.endLine, token.endColumn, ret, token.image);
}
```

This is an infinite loop that keeps running as long as `jj_2_17(2)` returns `true`, but **appears** to do nothing upon that result. It breaks **out of** `label_23` when the expression was `false`. To confuse future readers even more, it then actually *does* things only if the expression is `true` (as it breaks on `false`), namely the last three lines.

For futher information, the `label_23` is simply a label that may only be used on `while` and `for` loops. You can then break **out of** that loop when using `break labelName;`.

Example that breaks out of an outer loop from within an inner loop:

```
outerLoop: for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    innerLoop: for (int j = 0; j < max2 - i; j++) {
        if (something) {
            break outerLoop;
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

You can actually also use `continue` in combination with labels.

Then we see a scoped block without guard that always returns `ret`:

```
{
    if (true) {
        return ret;
    }
}
```

So it's all valid. I think we can also conclude with high chance that this code has been machine-generatd.

Comment: Does it appear that this class was done manually given its size and having to manually code all the labels?

Comment: @Nederealm I would say this code has strong indications it was machine generated.

Comment: To answer your point on labels only being able to used with while or for loops, technically thats not only the case. A break statement is also valid for a labelled block without a loop. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

What maybe largely confused here is that if-else block inside the while.

> ```
> if (jj_2_17(2)) {
>     ;
> } else {
>     break label_23;
> }
> jj_consume_token(DOT);
> jj_consume_token(IDENTIFIER);
> ret = new QualifiedNameExpr(ret.getBeginLine(), ret.getBeginColumn(), token.endLine, token.endColumn, ret, token.image);
> ```

this is in fact nothing other than a negated if:

```
if(!jj_2_17(2)) {
    break label_23;
}
jj_consume_token(DOT);
jj_consume_token(IDENTIFIER);
ret = new QualifiedNameExpr(ret.getBeginLine(), ret.getBeginColumn(), token.endLine, token.endColumn, ret, token.image);
```

So in fact this code just returns the last `QualifiedNameExpr(/*...*/);` that could be parsed.

Concerning the "unreachable throw" you mention in comments. Just imagine what happens when you create a method (in eclipse or netbeans) and don't add a return statement.

The generated code (assuming this is generated code here) then contains no return statement and suddenly you get to throw the Error. This leads to eclipse/netbeans/[insert IDE here] telling you "Missing return statement in function", which is exactly what this statement is there for...